# Opera не отправляет post

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Есть следующий js код, который используя ajax и jquery отправляет данные в БД:

```
$('#add_data').submit(function()
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "/send_data/",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(html)
                {
                    $("#echo_result").html(html);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Html код формы следующий:

```
<form method="post" id="add_data">
<input type="submit" value="add" class="submit">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
</form>
```

и таких форм на странице много, отличаются они только значением скрытого поля id. Скрипт работает во всех браузерах, кроме оперы 9.64, в ней срабатывает только каждая первая форма на странице, остальные при клике просто обновляют страницу.

Есть мысли, что ей не нравится?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас одинаковый **id** на всех формах? Такого быть не должно, т.е. это надо знать, как "отче наш"! **id** - это уникальный идентификатор и может быть только у одного элемента на странице. Задайте для форм класс "add_data"

Comment: Чот я тупанул конкретно :) Спасибо большое :)